# strange Train and test set are not compatible error in weka

Tags: weka

I have read many solution about this error. But my problem is definitely different from the others: I have a "train" dataset(arff) and a "test" dataset(arff), both these two arff have an attribute "id"(string). **It works well if** I 'remove' "id" of these two arff at the same time(if I don't remove the id in "test" I will get an error); *what confuse me is that my friend can do it by remove **only** the "id" in "train", so his output will contains the "id"*.
(since he didn't remove the "id" in the "test", the number of attribute will not be the same, and this is against what I read that the number of attribute should be exactly the same).

I really need an output that can contain the "id". 
Maybe I did something wrong with the "remove"? I read somewhere said that the test feature may be superior to that of train. And also a paragraph talking about how to remove:"Instead of using a nominal ID attribute, declare it as STRING 
attribute. With this you don't have to declare each possible value 
like with NOMINAL attributes and it therefore doesn't matter what 
strings are used in the test set that you're trying to use the trained 
model on. In order to be able to work with this STRING ID attribute 
you have to use the FilteredClassifier in conjunction with the Remove 
filter (package weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute) and your original 
base classifier. This setup will remove the ID attribute for the 
learning process (i.e., the base classifier), but you'll still be able 
to use it outside for tracking instances. "
http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/use-saved-model-td22857.html

Anyone have an idea?

Any help will be appreciated.

my 2 arff, left: train; right: test
[image]

left: output of myfriend with id such as test_subject1005 ; right: my output
[image]

Comment: supplementary infomation: we use WEKA 3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got my solution. Just click directly the "supplied test set" and in the prompt interface click "Yes". That all! (It seems that I did not see this prompt before, so I did not try)

[image]